# Oauth 2 (Passport.js) login should never fail, right?

Tags: node.js, express, oauth, oauth-2.0, passport.js

### **If I have an Oauth 2 login for Google (using Passport.js/Express) and the user has not ever accessed my site before, the following will happen:**

---

### OPTION 1: First Time User

User  `->`  clicks Google Oauth 2 login  `->`  Backend stuff happens  `->`  User is logged in

---

### OPTION 2: Returning User

User  `->`  clicks Google Oauth 2 login  `->`  Backend stuff happens  `->`  User is logged in AND the user's data from database is retrieved

---

### OPTION 3: User can't Login to their Google Account

User  `->`  clicks Google Oauth 2 login  `->`  can't login because the user forgot his Google password/email

---

While, the first two options will be the same, except for the fact that for ****Option 1**** I'll be POSTING to the database and for ****Option 2**** I'll be GETTING from the database.
However, the third option isn't my problem, when the user is trying to login to Google, they have already been redirected to `accounts.google.com/signin/(...)`. What I'm trying to say is, if option 3 occurs, there's really no code that I need to write for that situation.

So, whether it's a first time user or a returning user, if the user is accessing my site via oauth 2, either they will login to Google succesfully and I will get the data or they won't be able to login and none of the user's info will be sent to me, but either way, I never technically have to handle that operation failing, because it never will?

To give some context, the reason why I ask this is because I'm writing the code for deserialization and I realized that `done(null,user)` is sufficient because there will never be an error for deserialization, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OPTION 3**

You are right that you don't have to write any code here, because you have externalised sign in to the Authorization Server.

**OPTION 1**

The user signs up via a POST which creates the user in the Authorization Server - but not in your own data.

**OPTION 2**

It is common after login to send the access token to your API to get user info. When required you can create the user in your own database if it does not exist already.

**ERROR HANDLING**

Generally the Authorization Server may return error responses to you in some cases, in which case it will give you a code and description - as in [step 10 of my write up](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/26/basicspa-oauthworkflow/).

**MORE ABOUT USER DATA**

My [User Data](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/02/user-data/) blog post explores identifying new and existing users in further detail, in case useful.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it! Maybe you could answer this questions as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63286397/how-to-read-the-cookie-on-the-client-side-react-that-was-set-via-passport-on-t