# How to read the cookie on the client side (react) that was set via Passport on the Server side (node-express)?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies, authorization, passport.js

How to read the cookie on the client side (react) that was set via Passport on the Server side (node-express)?

The cookie is setup correctly and can be serialized and deserialized on the server side as shown in the below code:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

How can I read this cookie on the client side (React)?

I don't have much experience with cookies, but I've seen the below solutions:

```
import React from 'react';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

class App extends React.Component {
     this.state = {
        username: Cookies.get('username')
     }

//  more code....
}  


import React from 'react';
// other imports...
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';

const cookies = new Cookies();

class App extends React.Component {
     this.state = {
        username: cookies.get('username')
     }

//  more code....
```

And many others... but it seems like to read the cookie you have to know the `username` or `key` to get the value of it. Since Passport.js created my cookie in the `serializeUser` method, I don't know what the `key` value is. Does anyone know what the key value is or how to read a cookie created by passport?

Comment: Do you see the cookie in the browser's dev tools?

Answer (score 1):

The cookie will be HTTP Only and not readable on the client side. However, you can easily do this:

- Create a server side API route
- Perhaps at GET /api/user/current
- This endpoint does the above cookie deserialization then returns a JSON object

The client side browser code then just does an Ajax GET to the above endpoint.

Comment: Thank you, I considered that as well! I don't have much experience working with cookies, but isn't one of the main use cases for a cookie that I can decode the cookie on the client side so that I don't have to make a fetch request to the server for authorization?
If I have to result to a fetch request to the server, there really is no point to even having a cookie in the first place, am  I right or am I confused on the purpose of a cookie?